# Python YahooFinancials in combination with mysql connector lead to SSL error

Tags: python, ssl, ssl-certificate, yahoo-finance, database-connection

I have the following code

```
from mysql.connector import MySQLConnection, Error
from yahoofinancials import YahooFinancials

yahoo_financials = YahooFinancials('AAPL')
historical_stock_prices = yahoo_financials.get_prev_close_price()
```

This code causes the following error message:

```
OSError: [Errno socket error] [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:645)
```

The code does work very well without importing MySQLConnection but I need MySQLConnection later. Furthermore, on my machine MySQLConnection works in another python script without YahooFinancials.

Answer (score 0):

For those who are facing the same problem I found a solution. Just change the order of the imports. First import YahooFinancials then MySQLConnection:

```
from yahoofinancials import YahooFinancials
from mysql.connector import MySQLConnection, Error

yahoo_financials = YahooFinancials('AAPL')
historical_stock_prices = yahoo_financials.get_prev_close_price()
```

But unfortunately I don't know why it works this way.